Using Integral of Error as Input in Fuzzy Logic Controllers
I'm currently working on a control system for a doubly fed induction generator (DFIG) as part of my thesis project. Traditionally, fuzzy logic controllers (FLCs) use the error (e) and the derivative of error (\frac{de}{dt}) as inputs. However, in my implementation, I decided to use the integral of the error (\frac{1){s}) instead of the derivative. Surprisingly, this approach has yielded very good results in my simulations. Despite the positive outcomes, my thesis supervisor mentioned that they had never encountered the integral of error being used as an input in FLCs before. To ensure the robustness and academic validity of my approach, I need to back it up with some literature or resources that discuss this methodology. Has anyone here used the integral of error in their fuzzy logic controllers, or come across any papers or textbooks that mention this practice? Any guidance, references, or suggestions would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance for your help!
Edit: Additional Context To provide a bit more detail, my control strategy focuses on stabilizing the output and reducing steady-state error. The integral input seemed to naturally handle accumulation errors and improve performance, but I understand the importance of grounding this in established research. Any insights into the theoretical or practical aspects of this approach would be greatly appreciated.
